# Table or dictionary in code on a client for data that's not changed often?

Tags: schema, best-practices, client

Suppose I have a table where data won't be changed frequently. Say, a table "currencies" with a list of currencies which I accept on my website. I'd change it once in a while probably.
What are pros and cons of keeping "currencies" directly in code in a web application, as a dictionary, as opposed to keeping them in a database in a table? How is it usually done?

Answer (score 2):

Any data that can change should not be hard-coded into an app.  Especially if your app already uses a database.

Create a table to store currencies so you can update the list of currencies without needing to rewrite and redistribute the app.

As pointed out by Gareth Lyons in a comment, referential integrity relies on the database being self-contained; that is no references to code outside the database.  As an example, if you conduct transactions, you can maintain a list of valid currencies in a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Currencies
(
    CurrencyCode varchar(3) NOT NULL
        CONSTRAINT PK_Currencies
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
    , CurrencyName varchar(100) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO dbo.Currencies (CurrencyName, CurrencyCode)
VALUES ('East Caribbean Dollar', 'XCD')
    , ('Argentine Peso', 'ARS')
    , ('Armenian Dram', 'AMD')
    , ('Aruban Florin', 'AWG')
    , ('Australian Dollar', 'AUD')
    , ('Euro', 'EUR')
    , ('Azerbaijanian Manat', 'AZN')
    , ('Bahamian Dollar', 'BSD')
    , ('Bahraini Dinar', 'BHD')
    , ('Taka', 'BDT')
    , ('Barbados Dollar', 'BBD')
    , ('Belarusian Ruble', 'BYN')
    , ('Belize Dollar', 'BZD')
    , ('CFA Franc BCEAO', 'XOF')
    , ('Bermudian Dollar', 'BMD')
    , ('Indian Rupee', 'INR')
    , ('Ngultrum', 'BTN')
    , ('Boliviano', 'BOB');
```

And a list of transactions in a table list this:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.CurrencyTransactions
(
    TransactionID int NOT NULL
        CONSTRAINT PK_CurrencyTransactions
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
        IDENTITY(1,1)
    , CurrencyCode varchar(3) NOT NULL
        CONSTRAINT FK_CurrencyTransactions_CurrencyCode
        FOREIGN KEY 
        REFERENCES dbo.Currencies(CurrencyCode)
    , DebitAmount DECIMAL(38,4) NOT NULL
    , CreditAmount DECIMAL(38, 4) NOT NULL
);
```

Attempting to insert a transaction into the table, whether within your app, or *from any other source*, will result in the currency code being validated:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.CurrencyTransactions (CurrencyCode, DebitAmount, CreditAmount)
VALUES ('CAD', 1000000, 0);
```

Attempting to do the insert above results in this error:

> Msg 547, Level 16, State 0, Line 45
>   The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_CurrencyTransactions_CurrencyCode". The conflict occurred in database "tempdb", table "dbo.Currencies", column 'CurrencyCode'.

Comment: Also: a database table allows you to enforce referential integrity with FK's.

Comment: `Any data that can change should not be hard-coded into an app.` -- why? the downside is having to request data from a database each time.

Comment: The client may very well cache the data so it only needs to obtain it a single time, or perhaps every so often.  Storing data in code seems like a good thing at first, but quickly becomes very painful.  How would you add a new currency?  What if a client wants to add a new currency?

Comment: @MaxVernon -- a client won't want that. if I want to -- I'll just add it in code, what's the problem?

Comment: You say a client won't want that - do you mean no client is ever going to want a different currency?  You must be selling in USD.  So you're only selling to people locally?  Are you certain?  If there is even a tiny chance that someone will want to use another currency, it will be easier to build that in now, than to retrofit it if you have currencies stored in an enumeration, or some other code structure.

Comment: If you're looking for someone to confirm that its good or ok to store that in code, perhaps you should ask your question on [so].

Comment: @Torito so you accept, say, CAD and USD.  Obviously, the prices will be different when using one or the other.  How do you store the different prices in the DB without knowing which price belongs to which currency?

Comment: @MaxVernon, and if not?

Comment: @MaxVernon, no, a client has no ability to do so.